# Treat variable string as name of file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create dependency between variable and file.

Service structure:

```
import File from './'
export class Service {
    getConfiguration(name: string){
        return name.config;
    }
}
```

File structure:

```
export default {
   config: 
}
```

How to force the variable to be treated as a File name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    getConfiguration(name: string){
        return name.config;
    }
```

Will not work as you're trying to get the property `config` of the variable `name` which is a string.

If you want to get the property from `config` by using `name` you can use brackets to get the value of an index/property:

```
    getConfiguration(name: string){
        return config[name];
    }
```

Comment: I want to make that "name" is treated as "File" name, cause i have many Files and want to getting their config property dynamicly.

Comment: I have searched a bit and Jesper's solution is the easiest of what i find. I have changed my structure for that.

Answer (score 0):

To get a variable name as a string:

```js
function getVariableName(var) {
    const helper = {var};
    return Object.keys(helper)[0];
}
const myVar = 'mlkjmklj';
alert(getVariableName(myVar));
```